# Please assist the serverfault.com question "What would you do if you realized your email hosting provider could see your passwords?"

Tags: discussion

On http://serverfault.com there's the question [What would you do if you realized your email hosting provider could see your passwords?](https://serverfault.com/questions/524587/what-would-you-do-if-you-realized-your-email-hosting-provider-could-see-your-pas) It's on-topic there, so it's unlikely to get migrated. However I feel the answers it could get here were more adequate, so may I kindly suggest those of you who feel like it head over there and leave an **expert** answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers left there appear to be very decent and target the question very well. They explained the possible reasons behind storing the passwords in a recoverable format, and they explained the possible responses to such matters.

The actual reaction is up to the client himself. They could leave their current ISP or simply use a unique password, which has already been mentioned in the answers and the comments.

Comment: True, I just wanted to make sure nothing's been forgotten. And I am slightly concerned about [this answer](http://serverfault.com/a/524667/45248) claiming salting were useless...